# Netty: Should I close the Channel if it's a 'keep-alive' connection?

Tags: java, netty, keep-alive

I'm writing an HTTP server with Netty. I set the keep-alive option when I create server bootstrap.
`bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);`
Each time I write an HTTP response, I set the keep-alive header and close the channel after writing response.

```
rep.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
channel.write(rep).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to close the Channel.

Comment: Hard to see what the mystery is here. You can't seriously think that closing a channel constitutes keeping it alive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you are writing an HTTP 1.1 server, you should per default keep the connection open after sending the response. If, for some reason, you decide to close it anyway , you should include

```
Connection: close
```

in the response.

Note that

```
bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
```

turns on the keepalive option on the socket and has nothing to do with HTTP; rather, it is a kind of watchdog mechanim in order to detect broken connections in the absence of "real" traffic.

Comment: Thanks @forty-two! My intent was to keep the connection alive. Just to confirm this: do I need this part `.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);` after I finish writing response?

Comment: For most operating systems, the default `SO_KEEPALIVE` timeout is very long (e.g. 7200 seconds in Linux.), so I would not expect much from it.  You should just close the connection if no requests were sent by a client for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you also need to specify the length of the content:

```
  response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
```

so that the receiver can figure out where the message has ended. Else, the receive will just keep waiting for the message.

And, to be clear, you should not write ".addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);" if you want your connection to remain open.